# Save state of a PowerShell script to continue it later

Tags: powershell, csv, registry

I'm trying to fetch some registry parameters for about 4'000 machines with PowerShell. There's by no mean any chance that all machines are going to be up at the same time so I'd like to be able to save the list of machines that were already backed up for the script to only get the parameters from not already backed up machines.

I made a CSV file in the form of `Machine,Status` where the `Machine` column stores machines names and `Status` is supposedly either equal to `0` if the script hasn't run yet on this machine and `1` if the machine has already been backed up.
I'm already successfully parsing the machines names from the CSV where `Status = 0` and running my backup script for all machines that are up at script run time but I can't figure out how to set the variable `Status` to `1` back to the CSV (or from what I understood after some reading, to a temporary CSV that will later replace the original one).

My code is like:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path ./list.csv
  foreach ($line in $csv) {
     $status = $line.Status
     $machine = $line.Machine
     if ($status -eq "0") {
        [REG BACKUP SCRIPT]
        $status = 1 #Set the machine as done, but how to put it back to the CSV ?
Export-Csv -Path ./list-new.csv
```

I don't know where to put Export-Csv and after some attempts

Thanks

Comment: `Export-Csv ` should be at the end of the pipeline: `Import-Csv -Path ./list.csv |ForEach-Object { if ($_.Status -eq "0") { ...; $_.Status = 1 } } |Export-Csv -Path ./list-new.csv`

Comment: This seems to work, thanks ! I'm now piping `select *, @{N='Machine'; E={$_.Machine}}, @{N='Status';E={$_.Status}}` before `Export-Csv`  but the values returned are empty. Also, the pipe is freezing the console output until the script is done. Is there any way to display some kind of progress ?

Comment: Please, create a new question with a [mcve] showing what you exactly doing at the moment. You can use cmdlets like `Write-Host`, `Write-Information` or `Write-Progress` to display information during the process.